# Spring boot h2 database error getting driver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I'm trying to use h2 database in a springboot project, and i'm HikariDataSource, and i'm getting the following excepetion:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:h2:~/test
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:88) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:298) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:91) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:101) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:94) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvide...:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at...
```

I think that my pom.xml and my configuration class are correct

url: jdbc:h2:~/test
driverClassName: org.h2.Driver

Any clue on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using it for testing purposes?

Comment: Is there some root cause exception in your log? Such as ClassNotFoundException or some security exception?

Comment: I'm getting only that exception "No suitable driver found", i'm following this tutorial: http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angularjs-spring-data-jpa-crud-app-example/ and i also tried to use the source code provided by the author and i got the same error

Answer (score 2):

Add driver in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
 <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

https://dzone.com/articles/integrate-h2-database-in-your-spring-boot-applicat

Comment: I already did that, i'm following this tutorial: http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angularjs-spring-data-jpa-crud-app-example/ i tried with the source code of author and got same error

Answer (score 0):

Set the driver class name in the configuration for the pool.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30984463)